# Returning an accumulated query from a table with multiple entries with the same property_id and a personal amount

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables :

`Ingredients` with the following fields:

`ID`(numeric) `Ingredient`(text) `Plural`(text)

where `Ingredient` is the name of the ingredient and `Plural` is its plural name(ex:olive,olives)

and another table `Shopping_Ingredients` with the fields:

`Amount`(numeric) , `Ingredient_ID`(numeric)

I need a SQL statement that returns the added value of `Amount` for all the table `Shopping_Ingredients` and the `Ingredient` name (singular when it doesn't have plural or plural when it does)

example :

`Ingredients` :

1 'apple' 'apples'

2 'garlic' ''

`Shopping_Ingredients`:

1 1

2 1

3 1

2 2

3 2

return :

6 'apples'

5 'garlic'

Comment: If the ingredient doesn't have a plural, will the plural field be null or an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You didn't specify what database engine You use, here is version of query that works on SQL Server 2000 and newer (probably works on MySQL also):

```
SELECT 
    T.Amount, 
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Amount <= 1 THEN I.Ingredient
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Plural, '') = '' THEN I.Ingredient ELSE I.Plural END
    END
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(Amount) Amount, Ingredient_ID FROM Shopping_Ingredients GROUP BY Ingredient_ID
) AS T
INNER JOIN Ingredient I ON
    I.Ingredient_ID = T.Ingredient_ID
```

And here for SQL Server 2005 and newer:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(Amount) Amount, Ingredient_ID FROM Shopping_Ingredients GROUP BY Ingredient_ID
)
SELECT 
    T.Amount, 
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Amount <= 1 THEN I.Ingredient
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Plural, '') = '' THEN I.Ingredient ELSE I.Plural END
    END
FROM CTE AS T
INNER JOIN Ingredient I ON
    I.Ingredient_ID = T.Ingredient_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just typed in, but should get you pretty close

```
select count(*),
case x.plural='' then x.ingredient else x.plural end as Ingredient
from ingredients x
join Shopping_Ingredients y on y.ingredient_id=x.id
group by x.ingredient,x.plural
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select sum(s.Amount),
       case sum(s.Amount) 
            when 1 then max(i.Ingredient)
            else coalesce(max(i.Plural), max(i.Ingredient))
       end
from Ingredient i
left join Shopping_Ingredients s on s.Ingredient_ID = i.ID
group by i.ID
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but note that in OP's question plural can be '' (not null but empty string) and Amount is numeric, so You should check for Amount <= 1 instead of Amount = 1.

Comment: OP hasn't clarified whether plural would be empty string or null - example includes '', but question says "singular when it doesn't have plural" (which implies null, not empty string). I don't know about Romanian, but in English the *plural* is used for 0 quantity - so we say 0 apples, 1 apple, 2 or more apples. (Also, we don't know whether this is to be used for speakers of English, Romanian or some other language.)

Comment: @MarkBannister the app is going to be used for english users

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.amount, CASE WHEN a.plural is null then a.ingredient else plural end

(select i.id as id, i.ingredient as ingridient, i.plural as plural, SUM(si.amount) as amount
from ingredients i, shopping_ingridents si
where si.ingredient_id = i.id
group by i.id, i.ingredient, i.plural) a
```

Idea is to first select all the the data with SUM, that is select ingridient, plural and Sum of amount, then check if plural exists select plural else select ingridient.